# After Xcode 8 upgrade getting ld error: "can't map file, errno=22"

Tags: xcode8, build-settings

I'm working on a project we have had going for several years.  Just upgraded to Xcode 8 and now can't build **for testing** (the main build works fine).  This is the error:

```
 ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/Users/steve/Documents/XCode/xxx/xxx/Iphone/xxx/DerivedData/xxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxx.app' for architecture x86_64
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

In the output I *am* seeing the clang command with the -arch flag:
     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64

I don't know what is causing the -arch flag to be used.  I haven't changed anything in the build settings related to architecture (or anything else).  Nothing changed aside from upgrading to Xcode 8 and converting to Swift 3 (there is only one Swift file in the entire project, the rest is objective-c, but that one Swift file is the one called by the unit tests in the test project).

Does anyone know what might have changed in Xcode 8 to cause this?  Or how I can fix it?

Thanks,